# Dancing with Healing Vision Angelic Mix without turning into a pretzel

Tags: dance-dance-revolution

Stepchart referenced [here](http://www.ddrfreak.com/stepcharts/stepchart.php?song=healing2&mode=Single&difficulty=Maniac&code=Normal&Submit=Submit).

In DDR 5th Mix there is a song called Healing Vision (Angelic Mix). On Heavy (Hard) it is a 9-step song. I have previously passed this song by "ghetto stepping" it. This means I've used the same foot twice in a row, hitting two consecutive arrows, for many of the patterns. However, I'm older and fatter now. I'd like to find a smarter way to solve this song.

Referring to the stepchart and considering jumps (two simultaneous arrows) to be single steps I see the following pattern:

Step 1: Jump (no problem)
Step 2-8: Easy pattern
Step 9-15: Another easy pattern
Step 16-18: Seemingly easy pattern, twisting the torso to avoid ghetto stepping.
Step 19: Oh no! Either I must ghetto step here or turn myself into a pretzel!

If step 16 is started with the left foot (my inclination), step 18 is also done with the left foot, but that leaves me in an ugly spot trying to reach step 19 with my right, turning myself entirely away from the screen to do so.

If step 16 is started with the right foot (an unusual choice), step 18 is also done with the right foot, and that makes step 19 an easy left foot choice. That also makes step 20 an easy right foot choice, but then I'm left in a nearly identical pretzel vs. ghetto step choice for step 21!

How can I solve my dilemma? Hopefully someone else on these boards is/was an avid DDR player in years past and can expound some arcane secrets to the masses here on the *internets*.

Comment: This is a situation where I would do a reverse pivot so that my back is facing the screen momentarily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was going to be a followup comment, but I realized it's probably an answer.

On step 18, your right foot is on the right arrow.
On step 19, use your left foot to plant on the up arrow.
On step 20, pivot on your left foot and use your right foot to plant on the left arrow.
On step 21, pivot on your right foot and use your left foot to plant the down arrow.
On step 22, pivot on your left foot and user your right foot to plant on the up arrow. You're almost neutral again, unfortunately, you must immediately reverse your spin across the down arrow.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Yes! This is a spin. This is the "correct" way to do it as far as I know, but I really don't think there's shame in "ghetto stepping" it at all, especially if you're rolling your feet on the brackets. Some of my friends know really good players who created this image which you might find useful and interesting: http://imgur.com/6S0xBvq

Comment: @trainer-blue That is an amazing chart.  I hadn't thought that a 9-step would require me to completely turn my back on the screen (I thought that was 10+ territory.)  I self-taught myself all of my DDR skill as the scene where I live is/was pretty tiny. That will really help me. I haven't gotten this nailed down yet but I think this answer is correct.

Comment: @BlackVegetable I'm glad this was helpful, I literally stood up at work and ghost DDR'd to make sure I was giving the correct instructions :P